# Put an Image on a QPushButton

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm a beginner in PyQt and I have an image known as `add.gif`. I need to put this image in a `QPushButton` but I don't know how.

Answer (score 20):

Example:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        self.button.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('myImage.jpg'))
        self.button.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(24,24))
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def handleButton(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `self.button.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('myImage.jpg'))` works using PyQt5.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the same example from @NorthCat but for PyQt5:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.button = QPushButton('', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        self.button.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('myImage.jpg'))
        self.button.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(200,200))
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def handleButton(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming pyqt supports gif pictures, this should work

```
icon  = QtGui.QPixmap('add.gif')
button = QtGui.QPushButton()
button.setIcon(icon)
```

[QPushButton](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QPushButton.html)

> Push buttons display a textual label, and optionally a small icon.
>   These can be set using the constructors and changed later using
>   setText() and setIcon(). If the button is disabled, the appearance of
>   the text and icon will be manipulated with respect to the GUI style to
>   make the button look "disabled".

Comment: This isn't working, QtGui.QIcon("test.png") works...check your answer please